# Is there a way to ignore animations by appium while searching for elements?

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, lottie

I try to find elements on a page with a lot of animations. And it turnd out that it takes up to 5 seconds to find element even by Id or Accessibility Id.
After discussion with our developers we figured out tha animations has big JSON data. So, looks like appium tries to look through this JSON data and that's the reason of such a big delay.
Have you faced the same problems? Any ideas how to deal with it? Maybe there is a way to ignore animations/JSON data?

We use lottie framework for Android. Maybe there are some advices on settings for it?